# assignment from incompatible pointer type issues with dynamic stack in C

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I have two main problems.
My code is a stack (pile) of "elements", made with a struct as so:

```
typedef struct etCel{
    element *ele;
    struct cel *suiv;   
} cel;

typedef cel* pile;
```

The first problem is the "isEmpty" function, which generates a Segmentation fault:

```
int isEmpty(stack p){
    if(p->ele){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

int affiche_pile(pile p){
    printf("Valeurs de la pile:\n");

    while(p->ele){
        affiche_element(p->ele);
        printf("\n");
        p=p->suiv;
    }

    return 1;
}

int pile_est_vide(pile p){
    if(p->ele){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

pile push(stack p, element e){
    element *nvoele;
    nvoele = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
    stack ptmp = (stack)malloc(sizeof(cel));

    assert(ptmp);

    nvoele = &e;
    ptmp->ele = nvoele;
    ptmp->suiv = p; //ERROR HERE
    return ptmp;    
}

element pop(stack p){
    stack ptmp = init_stack();

    if(isEmpty(p) != 1){
        ptmp = p->suiv; //ERROR HERE
        free(p);
        return *(ptmp->ele);
    }else{
        printf("Erreur! La pile est vide!\n");
    }
}

int fill_stack(stack p, int q){
    element tmp = init_element();
    element *ptmp = &tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        input_element(ptmp);
        push(p, tmp);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The second problem is the assignment issue, which occurs in other functions such as this "pop" function:

```
element pop(stack p){
    stack ptmp = init_stack();
    if(isEmpty(p) != 1){
        ptmp = p->suiv;
        free(p);
        return *(ptmp->ele);
    }else{
        printf("Erreur! La pile est vide!\n");
    }
}
```

it generates this error:

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
>   default]    ptmp = p->suiv;

I'm sure it's just some kind of syntax error, any help is appreciated, thanks

---- Edit:
Here's what element looks like:

```
typedef struct etElement{
    float num;
} element;

element init_element(){
    element p;
    p.num=0.0;
    return p;
}

int affiche_element(element *p){
    printf("Valeur de l\'element:\n");
    printf("%f, ", p->num);
    printf("\n");
    return 1;
}

int affecte_element(element *p, float x){
    p->num = x;
    return 1;
}

int saisir_element(element *p){
    float x = 0;
    scanf("%f", &x);

    if(affecte_element(p, x)){
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return 0; 
    }
}

int compare_element(element *p, element *e){
    if(p->num > e->num){
        printf("%f > %f\n", p->num, e->num);
        return 3;
    }

    if(p->num == e->num){
        printf("%f = %f\n", p->num, e->num);
        return 2;
    }

    if(p->num < e->num) {
        printf("%f < %f\n", p->num, e->num);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And a minimal example of code:

```
int main(){

    //Initialisation
    stack p = init_stack();

    if(isEmpty(p)==1){
        printf("Empty.\n");
    }else{
        printf("Not empty.\n");
    }

    element e = init_element();
    element *pele = &e;
    assign_element(pele,3.0);

    //Empilation
    if(push(p,e)){
        p=push(p,e);
    }else{
        printf("Echec de l\'empilation.\n");
    }

    show_stack(p);
}
```

this is literally what I'm compiling minus some `printfs`

while I'm here, here's element:

```
typedef struct etElement{
    float num;
} element;
```

Comment: Regarding the first problem. You have to initialise pointers, otherwise they point to garbage. `p->elem` has probably not been initialised. Moreover, I assume you have initialised your pointer `typedef cel* pile`. Note also that you have declared the function `pile_est_vide` to receive as parameter a value. Is that intentional?

Comment: @nbro The pile is initialised in my main function, but why should I initialise p->elem for the first problem? As I'm checking whether it's `NULL` or not

Comment: In C you need to do "everything" manually. If a struct contains a pointer, when you create a variable of that struct, its pointer is not inialised to `NULL` but points to some area of memory which you do not "own". The usual way of programming, at least what I do in these cases, is to have a function that initialises my struct to a well-defined state.

Comment: At which lines do you get the error ?

Comment: Check here a few exercises which illustrate what I've just said: https://github.com/nbro/c-exercises

Comment: typedefs such as `typedef cel* pile;` only create confusion. Don't do this.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the first error is on the line: `if(p->ele){`  and the other is on the line: `ptmp=p->suiv;`

Comment: @MichaelWalz it's a class assignment so we don't have a choice

Comment: What is `element` ? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I know it may seem annoying, but show us also the definition of the function `init_pile()`.

Comment: @JessicaChambers please post a [MCVE] that means the minimum code that exposes the problem so we can copy/paste it on our computers, compile it and see what's wrong. And if there is some input, please post that too.

Comment: ... what you have posted, is maybe _minimal_, but not _complete_. We need something we can compile so we can reproduce the same situation that you have.

Comment: @nbro it won't let me edit the post again, so here's init_pile: `pile init_pile(){
 pile p=malloc(sizeof(pile));
 if(p){
  p->ele=NULL;
  p->suiv=NULL;
 }
 return p;
}
`

Comment: @JessicaChambers _it won't let you edit the post_ ?? What error message do you get from Stack overflow ??

Comment: We still don't know what `ppile`  is nor `init_element()` and `empile`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I had edited it too quickly, it's ok now. ppile is a pointer to a pile, a pile is a stack, init element creates an element and empile=push (studying in french)

Comment: Please post __all__ your code, `init_element`, `affecte_element`, `empile` and `affiche_pile` are still missing. _Il faut vraiment vous tirer les vers du nez_.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I usually get punished when I do that on here... You're damned if you do and you're damned if you don't

Comment: OK, without sufficient information I can't help. I'm giving up. Sorry.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No, I was just in the process of adding it.. thanks for your help though

Comment: `pile` or `stack` ? Please make up your mind.

Comment: @JessicaChambers From your `init_pile` function, it seems to me that you're initialising correctly your `pile`s.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I renamed it stack so it would be clearer for anglophones. It's the same thing

Comment: The definition of `init_stack()` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`struct cel` is defined nowhere.

```
typedef struct etCel{
    element *ele;
    struct cel *suiv;   // <<< this looks wrong to me
} cel;
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
typedef struct etCel{
    element *ele;
    struct etCel *suiv;   // <<< changement here
} cel;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything; even when I compile it it says it is already up to date

Comment: You have problems with your build system. You don't edit the correct file. Could you post a [mcve] ?